# Printing a row with a certain if then in a pd.Database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to identify outliers so I need to print a whole row where the `price` is equal to 820000 but I am I only get an error about how string indices need to be integers the only thing I can think of is should I use iloc? If so then how??

```
for row in autos.columns:
    if row["price"] == 820000:
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
autos.index[autos['price'] == 820000]
# or
autos[autos['price'] == 820000].index
```